# Randomly select a file from directory in PHP

Tags: php

So I have seen solutions of this, however my question is slightly different.

I want the file to have a character at the end.

So, for example, there is a directory called imgs:

**imgs**
contents: div.png, div2.png, divb.png, divab.png

I need to randomly select a file from this folder, but I need it to have a b at the end. So I could only get on either divb.png or divab.png.

If I get one that doesn't end in b, I need to reselect.
I currently have some code that gives me a timeout and doesn't reselect.

```
        function random_pic($dir = 'imgs'){
$files = glob($dir . '/*.png');
$file = array_rand($files);
if(substr($files[$file], -5)==$shortparam.".png"){
    return $files[$file];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT -----------------

```
            <?php
function random_pic() {
  $files = glob('imgs/*.png' );
  do {
    if ( isset( $file ) ) {
      unset( $files[$file] );
    }
    $file = array_rand( $files );
  } while ( ( substr( $files[ $file ], -5  != ( $shortparam . ".png" ) ) ) AND ( count( $files) > 0 ) );
  if ( count( $files ) > 0 ) {
    return $files[ $file ];
  } else {
    echo $file;
    return false;
  }
}
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 20; $k++){
        $image = random_pic();
        if($image == false){

        } else {
   // display image
```

This times out for some reason. 
(Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in file.php on line 84)

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Did you already try out any of the solutions offered below by Poiz & BenShoval? If what you intend is simply select a Random PNG image from a Directory containing a bunch of Images (including: PNG), Poiz's Solution may prove use though...

Answer (score 0):

I obviously don't have your files and your directory structure to try this code against, but I'm pretty confident it will solve your problem.

```
function random_pic( $dir = 'imgs' ) {

  if ( $files = glob( $dir . '/*.png' ) ) {

    do {

      if ( isset( $file ) ) {
        unset( $files[$file] );
      }

      if ( count( $files ) > 0 ) {
        $file = array_rand( $files );
      }

    } while ( ( substr( $files[ $file ], -5  != ( $shortparam . ".png" )   ) ) AND ( count( $files ) > 0 ) );

    if ( count( $files ) > 0 ) {

      return $files[ $file ];

    } else {

      return NULL;

    }

  } else {

    return NULL;

  }

}
```

You may want to consider returning FALSE instead of NULL if nothing is found since it's more versatile on the parent end.

Comment: @OllyScargill I fixed the error that was likely causing it to hang.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with a blend of `glob`, `array_walk()`, `array_rand()` and `preg_match()`.

```
<?php
    function random_pic($dir='imgs', $extension=".png", $endChar="b"){
        $files      = glob($dir . "/*{$extension}");
        $matches    = array();

        array_walk($files, function($imgFile, $index) use ($extension, $endChar, &$matches) {
            $pixName        = preg_replace("#" . preg_quote($extension) . "#", "", basename($imgFile));
            if( preg_match("#" . preg_quote($endChar) . "$#", $pixName)){
                $matches[]  = $imgFile;
            }
        });

        return (count($matches))? $matches[array_rand($matches)] : null;
    }

    $randomPic = random_pic(__DIR__. "/imgs", ".png", "b");

    // OR JUST USE THE DEFAULTS SINCE THEY ARE JUST THE SAME IN YOUR CASE:
    // $randomPic = random_pic();
    var_dump($randomPic);
```